# SQL Server 2012 Tutorial for beginners: Analysis Services - Data Mining

Tags: sql-server, data-mining

I am looking for a simple tutorial for SQL Server 2012 SSAS and DM, for non-CS (business) students. Ideally based on the AdventureWorksDW DB that comes with SQL server. I've seen "SQL Server 2012 Tutorials: Analysis Services - Data Mining" by MSFT, but it requires a long list of setup steps, to create a data source, the cube, models etc. Similarly with the tutorial here: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/143031/building-your-first-data-cube/.

Is there an existing project my students can just load into SQL server (cube / models etc) and immediately start playing with: i.e. visualizing and exploring a cube, running built-in DM algorithms and understanding the results etc? Can you send a link, necessary steps?

Thanks,

-- Shaul

Answer (score 1):

Check out the link below. You can download the files under "Tools and Utilities". A very helpful resource . The examples are based on Adventure Works database.

- http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/books/microsoft-data-warehouse-dw-toolkit/